# Singleton scope throwing error in dagger 2

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a pojo, decorated with Dagger 2's @Singleton annotation

```
@Singleton
public class CommonDataSingleton {
   private String authToken;
   private boolean isAuthenticated;
}
```

I have to inject this as a singleton in an activity.

I have created a module to tell how the object of CommonDataSingleton should be created.

```
@Module
public class SingletonModule {

    @Provides
    CommonDataSingleton getCommonDataSingleton() {
        return new CommonDataSingleton();
    }
}
```

And a component describing the places where the object should be injected

```
@Component(modules = {SingletonModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
    void inject(LoginPresenter loginPresenter);
}
```

Along with this I have another Component for injecting completely different objects.

```
@Component(modules = {PresenterModule.class})
public interface DiComponent {

    //to update the fields in the activities
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);

    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);

}
```

But I get this weird error stating 
`DiComponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:
@Singleton test.in.singleton.CommonDataSingleton`

Comment: The error does not seems to android related, but has to do with my understanding of scopes in dagger and how a singleton is generated...

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you some sketch, haven't tested it. Let me know whether some edits must be done here, but the concept is the following:

```
public class CommonDataSingleton {
   private String authToken;
   private boolean isAuthenticated;
}

@Module
public class SingletonModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    CommonDataSingleton getCommonDataSingleton() {
        return new CommonDataSingleton();
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {SingletonModule.class})
public interface SingletonComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
    void inject(LoginPresenter loginPresenter);
    CommonDataSingleton providesCommonDataSingleton();
}

@YourCustomScopeHere
@Component(modules = {PresenterModule.class}, dependencies = {SingletonComponent.class})
public interface DiComponent {

    //to update the fields in the activities
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);

    void inject(HomeActivity homeActivity);

}
```

Comment: what is that `@YourCustomScopeHere`, can it not be scopped?

Comment: Try to compile without it.

Comment: Nope not working.... `error: di.components.DiComponent (unscoped) cannot depend on scoped components:
@Singleton di.components.SingletonComponent`